# Como Mostrar Produtos en Ticket

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente codigo para imprimir un ticket, pero me marca error en el dataGridView1, el error es el siguiente( the name dataGridview1 does not exist in the current context) foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in dataGridView1.Rows) lo marca despues de que escribo el foreach

CrearTicket ticket = new CrearTicket();

```
            ticket.TextoIzquierda(" ");
            ticket.TextoCentro("TICKET CIERRE DE CAJA");
            ticket.TextoIzquierda(" ");
            ticket.TextoExtremos("FECHA : " + txtFechaV.Text, "HORA : " + txtHora.Text);
            ticket.TextoIzquierda(" ");
            ticket.EncabezadoVenta();
            ticket.lineasGuio();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                ticket.AgregaArticulo(fila.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), int.Parse(fila.Cells[0].Value.ToString()), decimal.Parse(fila.Cells[3].Value.ToString()));
            }
```

Comment: Debes poner el error que te sale y detallar más tu pregunta. De lo contrario, es difícil ayudarte.

Comment: The name 'dataGridView1' does not exist in the current context, cuando escribo el  dataGridView1.Rows
                                                                                                   
 foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    ticket.AgregaArticulo(fila.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), int.Parse(fila.Cells[0].Value.ToString()), decimal.Parse(fila.Cells[3].Value.ToString()));
                }

Comment: Es obvio no? Dice que la variable no existe. Revisa que el objeto `dataGridView1` exista. Quizá tiene otro nombre, o es que lo tienes que jalar de tu otro form.

Comment: Si pero como lo jalo de otro Form?, porque en el nuevo form no tengo un gridview

Answer (score 0):

Antes de mostrar el otro formulario, puedes tener un método que cargue la información del ticket.

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();  
form2.LoadTicketInformation(dataGridView1);
form2.Show();
```

El método `LoadTicketInformation` recibe el dataGrid y puedes hacer el foreach.